# Why does python become unresponsive when I use LaTeX to render text?

Tags: python, matplotlib, compiler-errors, latex, freeze

I'm currently using `python 2.7.11` running my code in `command prompt`. I am using `matplotlib` to create 3D figures for my `LaTeX` document. However when I try to use `LaTeX` to render my text for the images I receive a windows error message telling me `python.exe` has stopped working and I must close the program. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I'm not tec savvy, so simple answers would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Code**

The minimum code for this error is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

Module_Colour = '#F0AE1E'

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X_arr = numpy.array([1.0,0.0,0.0])
Y_arr = numpy.array([0.0,1.0,0.0])
Z_arr = numpy.array([0.0,0.0,1.0])
O_arr = numpy.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])

pyplot.quiver(O_arr,O_arr,O_arr,X_arr,Y_arr,Z_arr,
              pivot='tail', length=1.0, linewidth=2.5,
              color = Module_Colour)

pyplot.savefig('C:/Users/alexd/Documents/University/Physics/Physics Figures/fig.jpeg', bbox_inches='tight')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: run in console/terminal/cmd.exe and maybe it displays some error message.

Comment: @furas Is `command prompt` not the same as `cmd.exe`? If it is, no error is displayed apart from a window that pops up to tell me `python.exe` has stopped working and to close program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `pyplot.show()` *blocks* until you close the window.

If you are generating plots for your LaTeX documents, just remove `pyplot.show()`.

Make sure that Python can actually *find* `latex`, `dvipng` and `gs`. (I would expect you to get a error message if that is not the case, but I haven't used python/matplotlib on ms-windows, so I'm not sure.) That is, their location should be in your `PATH` environment variable. See the [matplotlib documentation on environment variables](http://matplotlib.org/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#environment-variables).

Try the following in an interactive Python session:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['latex', '--version'])
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
0
```

The stuff about the TeX version might well be different; it depends on which version of which TeX distribution you're using.
*Most important* is the last line; this is the return value of `subprocess.call` and *should* be 0, indicating that the command return no error.

If the `subprocess.call` raises an exception (like below; not sure if it will be the same on ms-windows), you need to modify the `PATH` so that python can find LaTeX and the other things it needs.

```
>>> subprocess.call(['foo', '--version'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Edit:**
If this is not the problem, it could be that is it TeX that is not quitting. Try running the script. When you get the error dialog, look in the task manager if there is still a (la)tex process running. Look at the LaTeX code that you use, and try running it in LaTeX to check that it is actually valid. It might get hung on an error...

Comment: Unfortunately my return value is `0` and the return info (see comment below, wasn't sure if it is relevant) seems good. Although thank you, that was very helpful as I'd been wondering if it was my `PATH` for a while but didn't know how to check! So if it isn't my path what else may it be?

Comment: `>>> import subprocess      (new line)    

>>> subprocess.call(['latex', '--version'])    (new line)      

MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6100 (1.40.17) (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)     (new line)     

Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2016 Han The Thanh     (new line)    

TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.        (new line)

compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8       (new line)

compiled with libpng version 1.6.24; using 1.6.24       (new line)

compiled with poppler version 0.46.0       (new line)

compiled with jpeg version 8.4       (new line)

0`

Comment: @AldaHunter The good news is that this confirms that latex can be found. :-) Try adding an explicit `exit()` at the end of your script, although that shouldn't be necessary. I've never seen this behavior, so it is probalby some ms-windows specific weirdness.

Comment: I have added the `exit()` code but still `python.exe` stops responding before the image is saved :,-(

Comment: @AldaHunter Look at the processes like I mentioned in my edit. Any tex-related processes still running?

Comment: When I run my code, `python.exe` appears (as expected) which appears to open up `kpsewhich.exe` (which is a `standalone path lookup and variable extension for Kpathsea1` from its description), this then closes suddenly before `python.exe` stops working! I cannot find any LaTeX or TeX processes (although maybe they start and finish too quickly to be seen). And I'm not sure what code to test in LaTeX, because as you can see from the minimal example I don't use any LaTeX code (although may be hidden in the matplotlib files somewhere). It seems a very weird problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133023/discussion-between-roland-smith-and-aldahunter).