# How to put 'underbar' below a letter (underscored characters) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Unfortunately due to a problem with windows I cannot render any of my `matplotlib` text with `LaTeX`. So basically I need away already in `matplotlib's` text handling to place a line underneath a letter.

So far the closest I have is `ax.text(x,y,z, r'$\mathbf{\underbar r}$')`, but this just produces `_r`. So if there is a way to get this bar under the 'r' that would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have already tried `ax.text(x,y,z, r'$\underline{\mathbf{r}}$')` but this doesn't seem to work, :,(

**Edit**

Just realized that you can 'cheat' `matplotlib` :D by placing text in the exact same position with just an `\underbar`, which makes it appear under the letter. i.e. `ax.text(x,y,z, r'$\mathbf{r}$')` followed by `ax.text(x,y,z, r'$\mathbf{\underbar}$')`

But a quicker way would still be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By "problem with windows I cannot render any of my matplotlib text with LaTeX" you mean you cannot use `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`?

Comment: What about `$\mathbf{\underline{r}}$`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes unfortunately it sees to crash `python.exe`, here are my earlier posts on the issue!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib/41453758?noredirect=1#comment70489569_41453758

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600714/why-does-python-become-unresponsive-when-i-use-latex-to-render-text/41600957?noredirect=1#comment70440897_41600957

Comment: @Werner I have tried that, but unfortunately you need `LaTeX` to understand and render the `underline` command!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some negative spacing between the underbar and your character. In this case it seems that tripling the `\!` works well:

```
ax.text(2,7, r'$\mathbf{\underbar \!\!\! r }$')
```

[image]