# Matplotlib bold and underline part of a plotted title based on a given string

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of chars that I plot as title with its corresponding x coordinates using matplotlib's text. I have a string that will exist as a pattern within the plotted text. How do I bolden and underline the string once found in the title. Here is what I have so far.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

st = ['D', 'K', 'J', 'K', 'D', 'J', 'K', 'D', 'K', 'D', 'D', 'T', 'T', 'D']
word = 'KDDT'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
st1 = [x for x, y in enumerate(st)]
ax.set_xticks(st1)
loc = 1.2
arg = dict(fontsize=10, va='top')

for x, y in enumerate(st): 
    ax.text(x, loc, y, **arg )
plt.plot(range(14), range(14))   
plt.show
```

I get the title on top but I am not sure how to proceed with the bold and underline of the word KDDT within the title on the plot. The word can occur anywhere within the st list.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937048/make-part-of-a-matplotlib-title-bold-and-a-different-color) is how to make part of a title bold. I'm not sure if one can underline text with matplotlib's text. But you can [use latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727368/underlining-text-in-python-matplotlib) for it.

Comment: I saw that answer of yours earlier but it is different from what I need. The title is a plot on its own with its own coordinates and I will need to compare the word with contents of the title then bold and underline once found

Comment: So in that answer it is shown how to make some text bold. I strongly doubt you can underline text easily, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642265/how-to-put-underbar-below-a-letter-underscored-characters-in-matplotlib) would be another workaround. So in total I would opt for not underlining anything, because that just is too hard.

Comment: I guess this will be tough to do then. Hopefully, I can find a way around it